# Difference between reading and parsing

Tags: c, parsing

I somewhere read that `scanf` in **C** programming language *parses* the data (http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)- can someone please explain what that means (I tried googling it but couldn't get it properly).

Comment: Reading just means consuming bytes in a stream indiscriminately. Parsing constructs an AST for a particular syntax/grammar expected in the bytes. `scanf` does some rudimentary parsing which is what the format specifiers are for.

Comment: @Rafael: “Reading” does not mean “consuming,” and certainly not consumingly indiscriminately, and “parsing” is a general term, not specific to ASTs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In this context, it seems that the community disagrees with you, unless you have a better answer?

Comment: @Rafael: No, it does not seem that. As in the up-voted and accepted answer, reading data is getting data into the program. That does not indicate either consuming (which is destructive) or lack of discrimination, and parsing data is any of a variety of analysis of the data, not specifically an AST.

Comment: You're trying quite hard to prove yourself. You're needlessly nit-picking at minutiae. The pseudo-code is reading data from a device in stream-like fashion which is analogous to "consuming." If you don't like the word choice used, that's your problem. "A progran can read raw data without knowing what the data means. The program will just get a sequence of bytes without knowing what these numbers mean." Reading is indiscriminate. Again, if you don't like my word choice, that's your problem. Your nit-pick abour parsers and ASTs ignores the allusion to byte discrimination which was my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Parse data" means that you take some raw data and put a specific meaning into the data.

"Read data" is a less specific term but in this context is can refer to "getting raw data into your program from some device". Here "some device" can be many things - it can be a terminal (stdin), a disk, a network connection and so on. A program can read raw data without knowing what the data means. The program will just get a sequence of numbers (bytes) without knowing what these numbers mean. In pseudo-code:

```
 // READ DATA
 unsigned char array[some-size];
 size_t index = 0;
 while(input-device-has-data)
 {
     array[index] = get-input-from-device();
     ++index;
 }
```

After this loop that reads data, the array may contain:

```
array[0]: 74
array[1]: 79
array[2]: 69
array[3]: 32
array[4]: 52
array[5]: 50
array[6]: 0
```

A sequence of numbers that doesn't really seem mean anything. So the next step is to setup some rules for the data to make them meaningful. The first step is the encoding, i.e. what does the number 74 mean? One such encoding is the ascii table that defines how numbers are translated into characters. Using the ascii table the numbers above become:

```
array[0]: J
array[1]: O
array[2]: E
array[3]: space
array[4]: 4
array[5]: 2
array[6]: NUL
```

Then you can setup rules for the data you want your program to receive. In this simple example the rule would be something like: `name age`

So in your program you will like to "convert the raw data" into two variables. One variable that holds the name and another variable that holds the age. In pseudo-code:

```
string name = get_name(array);
int age = get_age(array);
```

That is "to parse" data, i.e. take some raw data (a sequence of numbers) an put specific meaning (semantic) into the data while following some rules for the data (syntax).

And that is exactly what the scanf-family functions can do for you. In this case like:

```
// Parsing
char name[20];
int age;
int result = sscanf(array, "%19s %d", name, &age);
```

Here `sscanf` parses the raw data contained in the `array` and tries to map the raw data into a word (aka name - max 19 characters) followed by a space followed by a number (aka age). This is the rules that the format specifier sets, i.e. the string `"%19s %d"`.

If `sscanf` can parse the data according to those rules, it will return the value 2 to telle that data was parsed into 2 variables and the variable `name` will hold the first word and the variable `age` will hold the number. That's what parsing is about.

Answer (score -2):

You read it wrong, the `scanf()` function scans information from stdin and converts the information read according to what type modifier characters (e.g %s, %d, %c) are specified. Parsing is a much more sophisticated technique that involves tokenizing the input, validating it against a set rules in a context free grammar, and building an abstract syntax tree to verify if the input is part of a language.

Comment: No, there are plenty of parsers that don't use tokenizers and CFG. That's like saying it's only a car if it has a diesel engine - Herr Diesel was important to the history but there are better technologies now. Every parser I've created this century has used PEGs instead and many of them use direct instantiation of the final concrete object graph rather than AST.

Comment: Sure you may argue that there are handful or parsing algorithms that do not make use of tokenizers and CFG, but the real question is whether or not `scanf()` reads or parses the data. And according to scanf(3) it does not do any sort of parsing rather it scans information from stdin.